# Handle malformed xml soap messages in WCF

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

I'm getting malformed xml from a soap webservice that I have to use from WCF. It returns invalid xml characters into messages. Of course, WCF reports invalid xml exceptions when receiving message. I could easily fix this issue if I had a way to modify incoming message before it gets parsed. Is there a way to do this?

I've already tried handling this with `IClientMessageInspector` but had no luck. It provides access to `Message` class, but the only way you can get to it's body and change it is when it's valid xml.

Comment: It may help to know what exactly is wrong with the incoming soap message. There are some incompatabilities at times between Java Web Services and .NET Web Services. But by knowing what the exact problem is, perhaps we can use something native to WCF to "fix" the problem without having to muck around with the actual incoming SOAP message before letting WCF handle it.

Comment: There are incorrect 0x03 characters in returned data.